# Calculators packages : TI and Casio

Tags: color, option-clash

I'm trying to print the keys of my calculators in a TeX document, thanks to these packages :

- https://ctan.org/pkg/tipfr
- https://ctan.org/pkg/graph35

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[color=real]{graph35} % Casio calculator
\usepackage{tipfr} % TIcalculator
\begin{document}

On a Casio calculator, type \key[scale=2]{sin} ; On a TI calculator, type \Touche .

\end{document}
```

I get an error saying :
*! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H  for immediate help.
...
l.9 \RequirePackage
[zerostyle=d]{newtxtt}
The package xcolor has already been loaded with options:
[]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
[dvipsnames,table]
Adding the global options:
,dvipsnames,table
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.*

But even if I put *,dvipsnames,table* in my documentclass declaration, there is still an error. Does anyone would know how to prevent that clash between these two packages ?

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 6):

Just swap the order so the package using xcolor options is first

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tipfr} % TIcalculator
\usepackage[color=real]{graph35} % Casio calculator

\begin{document}

On a Casio calculator, type \key[scale=2]{sin} ; On a TI calculator, type \Touche .

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `tipfr` package has

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
```

while `graph35` has

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
```

which loads `xcolor` without options.

Thus the order of the packages has to be reversed. If you need to pass further options to `xcolor`, load it with the options you need first, including `dvipsnames` and `table`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

% uncomment the following if you need more options to xcolor
%\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,<other options>]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tipfr} % TIcalculator
\usepackage[color=real]{graph35} % Casio calculator

\begin{document}

On a Casio calculator, type \key[scale=2]{sin} ; On a TI calculator, type \Touche .

\end{document}
```

For instance, you may want to use `monochrome` for printing on a black-and-white printer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,monochrome]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tipfr} % TIcalculator
\usepackage[color=real]{graph35} % Casio calculator

\begin{document}

On a Casio calculator, type \key[scale=2]{sin} ; On a TI calculator, type \Touche .

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it works !
In order to be more independant next time, where can I find the rules to load packages in the right order ?

Comment: @Alex there are no rules, it is mostly trial and error... see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635725/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-the-correct-order-to-load-packages and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3090/packages-that-need-to-be-included-in-a-specific-order.